# Laravel 5.1 to shared hosting with FTP only

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I'm having trouble deploying laravel 5.1 to my shared hosting.

I have a current domain name : `stefanogroenland.nl/laravel/public` which shows the laravel welcome screen. Now i want to remove the need of /public so all my url's are nice and clean. Does anybody know how to fix this? i can only use FTP

if anybody knows please reply!

My FTP files under httpdocs

[image]

Comment: Use this [link](https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/)

Comment: re uploading files to ftp. got lost a bit haha. Will use your link after upload and will reply back to you! thanks for replying!

Comment: After FTP uploading the files all i get is an 500 internal server error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Rename the server.php to index.php (no modifications)

2)  Copy the .htaccess from public

Changing .htaccess it a bit as follows for statics:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

If there are any other static files needed just add the extension to the previous declared list

Comment: freshly installed laravel 5.1 to my hosting and i get 500 errorcode

Comment: check your permission of index.php file . It should  0644.

Comment: my pleasure @StefanoGroenland . Happy coding :)